# Latex - Set Caption Tab.1 to Tab. S1

Tags: tables, numbering, captions

Is there a way to change the default caption numbering of:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{caption}
```

From `Tab. 1: caption` to `Tab. S1: caption` basically adding a string before the number that should be updated as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
```